# how to unlock the stream for individaul user during remote delivery in clearcase?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

Most of the time I have the users delivering from remote site but the problem is I would like to unlock the stream for only individual user whoever is delivering. In my site, the account of the user doesn't exist. Is there a way to unlock a stream for a certain user who is delivering from the remote site?

Answer (score 1):

No, for clearcase multi-site, the ownership is by sute, not by individual user.

If you are not talking about multi-site, but CCRC (Remote Client) or ClearTeam (for ClearCase 8.x), then you can lock a stream except for a user:

```
# Windows
cleartool lock -nusers auser stream:aStream@\aPVob

# Unix
cleartool lock -nusers auser stream:aStream@/vobs/aPVob

# Using the GUI (Elyahu)
From ClearCase Project Explorer -> Properties on the stream -> Lock <TAB> -> "Excluded users" section
     -> Add login names or Right-Click in the white area to open the options menu
```